# SwiftUI Navigation bar customize from SceneDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to delete the "Back" from the image below.

https://pasteboard.co/J8s2PTh.png

In scene delegate file, I customize the navigation back button, but i am trying to get rid of "Back" word.

```
   fileprivate func  setupAppearance(){

    UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: ImageText.leftArrow.string)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: ImageText.leftArrow.string)

}
```

I don't want to use navigationBarItem on NavigationView because i need to do this in all the views (there will be many)

```
.navigationBarItems(leading:

            Button(action: {

                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()

            }
            ) {
                HStack {
                    Image(ImageText.leftArrow.string).frame(width: 50, height: 44, alignment: .leading)
                }
            }
```

Is there a way to delete the "Back" word from SceneDelegate?

Comment: you can hide back button from navigation ....

Comment: That will hide the whole back button, i need to display  the customized "<"

Comment: you can do that by adding customize button

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61785454/1780632 here is how you can achieve that

Comment: it works, but now the icon "<" have a small delay appearing 0.5s

Comment: i need to setup something from the navigation view for the delay?
now it looks like this : https://ibb.co/FY7B2B8

Comment: isn't it good enough ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213922/discussion-between-jawadali-and-swiftios).